# retrieving similar data in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say I have the following table for example:

```
id  name
---------
1   Matt
2   Ryan
3   Joseph
4   Matt1
5   5Joseph
6   David
7   Matt_43
```

We see that Matt and Joseph has been repeated more than once i.e `Matt`, `Matt1` and `Matt_43`. Similarly `Joseph` is repeating twice.

Is there a way to retrieve such kind of data?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to them.)

Comment: Hint: Use `LIKE`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Kindly add sample output also

Answer (score 2):

You could self-join your table with a LIKE

For example:

```
select t1.id as id1, t1.name as name1, t2.id as id2, t2.name as name2
from your_table t1
join your_table t2
  on (upper(t1.name) like '%'|| upper(t2.name) ||'%' and t1.id <> t2.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like wildcard characters that have operator like '%matt%' this will return all the matt value even if the prefix or postfix would not match

here is the query

```
select name from emp where name like '%matt%' or name like '%joseph%'
```

Answer (score 1):

since oracle is very case sensitive even when 2 words are same
where
  one starts with capital letter 
  and second with small,

oracle will consider them two different data, to keep them in your search you would require this approach:
 `select name from emp where UPPER(name) like '%UPPER(Ryan)%';`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you need to retrieve data having similar text in column `name`, you can join the table to itself, use `like` in join condition and return `distinct` records as below.

```
select distinct t1.id as id, 
       t1.name as name
from table1 t1
join table1 t2
  on ((t1.name like '%'|| t2.name ||'%' or t2.name like '%'|| t1.name ||'%') 
      and t1.id <> t2.id);
```

**Result:**

```
+----+---------+
| ID |  NAME   |
+----+---------+
|  4 | Matt1   |
|  7 | Matt_43 |
|  1 | Matt    |
|  3 | Joseph  |
|  5 | 5Joseph |
+----+---------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/SCWITS40003)**

---

**Update:**

If you don't want the result to be case-sensitive, use `upper`

```
select distinct t1.id as id, 
       t1.name as name
from table1 t1
join table1 t2
  on ((upper(t1.name) like '%'|| upper(t2.name) ||'%' or upper(t2.name) like '%'|| upper(t1.name) ||'%') 
      and t1.id <> t2.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are defining 'similar', you could look at [`soundex()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions148.htm) or [`utl_match`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/UTL_MATCH.htm):

```
with demo (id, name) as
    ( select 1, 'Matt' from dual union all
      select 2, 'Ryan' from dual union all
      select 3, 'Joseph' from dual union all
      select 4, 'Matt1' from dual union all
      select 5, '5Joseph' from dual union all
      select 6, 'David' from dual union all
      select 7, 'Matt_43' from dual )
select id, name
     , soundex(name)
     , count(*) over(partition by soundex(name)) as count_similar
     , utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(name, 'Matt') as similarity_to_matt
from   demo
order by similarity_to_matt desc;

     ID NAME      SOUNDEX(NAME) COUNT_SIMILAR SIMILARITY_TO_MATT
------- --------- ------------- ------------- ------------------
      1 Matt      M300                      3                100
      4 Matt1     M300                      3                 96
      7 Matt_43   M300                      3                 91
      2 Ryan      R500                      1                 50
      6 David     D130                      1                 48
      5 5Joseph   J210                      2                  0
      3 Joseph    J210                      2                  0
```